# Problems with staggered image and comment

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have problems with the placement of the image and the comment. They are placed in a staggered way. I want them to be placed right next to each other, on a straight horizontal line. You can see the problem on the image below.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LCA72/8/)

[image]

I tried to add this code:

```
display:inline-block;
```

still don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCA72/15/)

Change your css code with this below code...

```
.CommentStyle {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 30px;
}

.CommentImage {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to .CommentStyle:

```
width: 500px;
display:inline-block;    
vertical-align: middle;
```

and add this to .CommentImage:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCA72/12/)

Explanation:

div is a block element, which means it takes the entire width unless limited by the width css property. Learn more here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/